# How to set auto-replies for certain days in Microsoft Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2010, visual-basic

I have a lazy colleague who always forgets to put her Out of Office on two days during the week when she is not at work. My question is, Is there a way in Microsoft Outlook via VB or a rule to send the auto replies on on certain days during the week?

For example person A is not in Tuesday, therefore a script triggers and the OOF is activated.

Is this possible?

Comment: What have you researched and/or tried so far?

Comment: I have done some research but come across absolutely nothing. Not asking for someone to do it for me, but to point me in the right direction would be valued greatly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tell her to create a rule "With Specific Words in the Message Header", then put in Mon/Tue/Wed/etc, then "Reply with this message" and enter the relevant message she wants to be sent to people. ***this solution requires the account to remain logged in to work***

If you want the rule to run when you are logged out of your account, instead of "Reply with this message" use "have server reply using a specific message".  A email template will open, enter the subject and content then click  "Save & Close" which will take you back to the Rules Wizard.

Comment: Amazing solution. I was looking everywhere, & everywhere it said that go for VBA, Client Rules, Macros etc.. But this one is genius. simple & correct

Comment: Im trying to do this using Outlook 365 but cant really understand where to find message header configurations...?