# Auto reply on one day a week

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Can someone show me how to set-up an auto reply for one day a week every week? using Outlook 2010. Basically we have some employees that only work certain days of the week and I want them to have an out of office on those days every week.

EDIT:
It is for one day every week. [Above](https://superuser.com/q/623199/441635) answer is not what I am looking for as it doesn't allow for a specific day of the week every week. The rules that is. You can only have a date range and not one every Friday for example.

Comment: This question has already been answered here: http://superuser.com/questions/623199/how-do-i-set-up-outlook-2010-to-send-auto-reply-based-on-the-time-and-day-of-the

Comment: Thanks for that, but it seems that it does it for a date range instead of specific days of the week. How does it know it must do it for every Friday for example?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Take a look at ***[ask]*** which may help explain the down votes.

Comment: This question has already an answer at [http://superuser.com/a/620882/146781](http://superuser.com/a/620882/146781), non-VBA, simple one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems indeed that time of the day is not possible to do through UI of Outlook, but you need rather to write custom VBA script. Here is the answer for the custom VBA script: [How do I set up Outlook to send a auto reply during a certain hour of the day every day?](https://superuser.com/questions/518729/how-do-i-set-up-outlook-to-send-a-auto-reply-during-a-certain-hour-of-the-day-ev)

UPDATE: 
There is also a workaround for this if you do not want to write any VBA scripts, check out this post here: [How to set auto-replies for certain days in Microsoft Outlook?](https://superuser.com/questions/620835/how-to-set-auto-replies-for-certain-days-in-microsoft-outlook/620882#620882)

Comment: Thanks I will do that instead, odd that they don't have that built in. For people that work certain days of the week.